# How to parse a simplified YAML file using AWK?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file (data.txt) that looks like this:

```
apple:
  weight: 15
  color: red
banana:
  weight: 30
  length: 12
grape:
  weight: 5
peach:
  weight: 25
  color: orange
  length: 4
```

Using bash, and awk, (and or sed), how would I pick out the values for the sub keys here?
I want to have a bash function such as:

```
   function get_value(parent_key, child_key){ ... }

   #Test 1
   expected=15
   actual=$(get_value(apple,weight)) # Apples have a weight

   #Test 2
   expected=red
   actual=$(get_value(apple,color))  # Apples have a color

   #Test 3
   expected=""
   actual=$(get_value(apple,length))  # apples don't have a length
   
   #Test 4
   expected=""
   actual=$(get_value(banana,color))  # no color defined
```

Sadly I don't have access to perl/python.
This isn't a YAML file, just data with colons separating keys and values.
The file is made up of a parent key, and a child key only.

I've tried something like this:

```
awk "/$key"'/ {found=1} found && /'"$child_key:"'/{print; found=0}' data.txt
```

But this doesn't handle the case where a child key doesn't have a value.

Comment: Seems like valid YAML tho, why not use a tool like [tag:yq]

Comment: no yq available :(

Comment: When dealing with yaml, you should really strive to use a proper yaml parser. If this isn't possible, then you could consider to first convert the input to a space seperated file: `parentKey.childKey value`, and then run over that and match `$1 == 'wantedParentKey.wantedChildKey'`.

Comment: Why _awk_? awk is optimal for data which come in tabular form. Of course you **can** do it in awk (or any other turing-complete programming language), but why not going for something more convenient? Many modern languages come with a YAML parser, which just slurps the data and produce a nested hash, where you can pick any value you like.

Comment: @user1934428 Sadly I have only bash commands, and awk/sed available to me :(

Comment: I doubt that you are really on a platform where there is no i.e. Perl or Ruby available (what bizarre operating system are you using then?), and even if this were the case, you can install them as you like.

Comment: @user1934428 it's not that unusual to only have mandatory POSIX tools available (which includes awk, sed, and grep but excludes perl, python, ruby, yq, jq, xmlstarlet, etc.) and not be allowed to install any others. I spent 30+ years working in such an environment and we do occasionally get people asking questions with similar constraints.

Comment: @CodingFrog using `-v` or one of the other ways to populate an awk variable from the value of a shell variable doesn't just look better than allowing a shell variable to expand to become part of the awk script itself, it's also more robust and leads to far less cryptic error messages and potentially harmful consequences if/when there's anything unexpected in the shell variable.

Comment: @EdMorton OK, thank you. That's good to know. Been finding AWK rather hard to follow so far.

Comment: @CodingFrog yeah, it takes some time to understand/accept that awk does all the common stuff for you related to text processing (reading lines, splitting them into fields, keeping track of line numbers and number of fields, etc.) and has a `<condition> { <action> }` body structure but once you wrap your head around that, awk is mostly just a tiny subset of C. The book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins is the best intro to and reference for awk.

Comment: Why there is not space before apple, but one space before banana, grape and peach?

Comment: @Daweo Thank you for spotting that. Have corrected the spacing now.

Comment: I always recommend people buy the book rather than providing the online link as that's the only income the author gets for both providing the GNU awk tool and also the documentation so it wouldn't be fair to have people use the online reference he also graciously provides without buying the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

get_value() {
    awk -v tgt_parent_key="$1" -v tgt_child_key="$2" '
        {
            gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
            key = val = $0
            sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",key)
            sub(/[^:]*:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)

            if ( val == "" ) {
                parent_key = key
                parent_val = val
                child_key = child_val = ""
            }
            else {
                child_key = key
                child_val = val
            }
        }
        (parent_key == tgt_parent_key) && (child_key == tgt_child_key) {
            print child_val
        }
    ' "$infile"
}

infile="$1"

#Test 1
expected=15
actual=$(get_value 'apple' 'weight') # Apples have a weight
printf 'expected="%s", actual="%s"\n' "$expected" "$actual"

#Test 2
expected=red
actual=$(get_value 'apple' 'color')  # Apples have a color
printf 'expected="%s", actual="%s"\n' "$expected" "$actual"

#Test 3
expected=""
actual=$(get_value 'apple' 'length')  # apples don't have a length
printf 'expected="%s", actual="%s"\n' "$expected" "$actual"

#Test 4
expected=""
actual=$(get_value 'banana' 'color')  # no color defined
printf 'expected="%s", actual="%s"\n' "$expected" "$actual"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
expected="15", actual="15"
expected="red", actual="red"
expected="", actual=""
expected="", actual=""
```

The above assumes that the way to tell a parent from a child key is that a parent doesn't have a value after the `:` while a child does. If that's wrong then fix your example to include a case where a parent has a value after the `:` and explain how to tell them apart.

Comment: Wow! That's so very helpful! Thank you so much. I'll try that out in the next hour. I've been struggling this this for hours. Thank again @EdMorton

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
apple:
  weight: 15
  color: red
banana:
  weight: 30
  length: 12
grape:
  weight: 5
peach:
  weight: 25
  color: orange
  length: 4
```

then

```
awk -v k1=apple -v k2=color 'BEGIN{FS=":[[:space:]]*"}/^[[:alpha:]]/{k=$0;next}{$0=k $0}k1==$1&&k2==$2{f=1;print $3}END{if(!f){print "not found"}}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
red
```

and

```
awk -v k1=apple -v k2=red 'BEGIN{FS=":[[:space:]]*"}/^[[:alpha:]]/{k=$0;next}{$0=k $0}k1==$1&&k2==$2{f=1;print $3}END{if(!f){print "not found"}}' file.txt
awk -v k1=grape -v k2=color 'BEGIN{FS=":[[:space:]]*"}/^[[:alpha:]]/{k=$0;next}{$0=k $0}k1==$1&&k2==$2{f=1;print $3}END{if(!f){print "not found"}}' file.txt
```

both give output

```
not found
```

Explantion: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator (`FS`) is colon followed by zero-or-more whitespace characters, then for line starting with letter I store that line in variable `k` and go to `next` line, so nothing else happens, for other line I prefix line by value stored in `k`, if 1st field is same as value in `k1` and 2nd field is same as value in `k2` (which were given as arguments) I set `f` to 1 and print 3rd field. After all lines were processed and nothing was found I output `not found`. Feel free to adjust that as I am not sure what exactly should be printed in that case.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: You should generally avoid setting FS to `:` (or `:[[:space:]]*`) and relying on `$2` for tasks like this as they'd fail if the value contained `:`, e.g. `ratio: 3:1` or `time: 02:30`.

Comment: I do like this very succent code, but I can confirm that if the value has a colon, it does fail. But thank you also for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

GNU AWK

```
#!/bin/bash

input=inputfile

getValue(){
    awk -v parent="$1" -v child="$2" '
        BEGIN{
           if (! parent || ! child){print "two args needed" ; exit} 
           output = "not found"
        }
        /^[^ ]/{found=0} 
        $0~parent{found=1; next} 
        found{
            if ($0~child){
                output=gensub(/^[^:]*: +/,"",1)
                exit
            }
        }
        END{
            print output
        }
    ' "$input"
}
```

Test

```
getValue 'apple' 'weight'
getValue 'apple' 'color'
getValue 'apple' 'length'
getValue 'foo' 'bar'
getValue 'foo'
```

Output

```
15
red
not found
not found
two args needed
```

Comment: I liked this one, but one requirement I forgot to mention is that it need to manage spaces in the values. This script only returns the first word in a value.
For example if we have apple: color: 'Dark Green', it will return 'Dark'.

Comment: @CodingFrog: updated. `output=gensub(/^[^:]*: +/,"",1) `

Comment: Yes! It works fine with that change on gawk. I see that gensub is specific to gawk. Tried it against mawk as well, and it doesn't know of a gensub. So may need to keep to the code posted earlier. Thank you!